# Herstein Problem No.13 Page 109

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Give an example of a finite non-abelian group $G$ which contains a subgroup $H_0 \neq (e)$ such that $H_0 \subset H$ for all subgroups $H \neq (e)$ of $G$.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the Quaternion group $Q_8$ and the subgroup $H_0=\{1,-1\}$

Comment: $Q_8=\{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ and $H_1=\{\pm1, \pm i\}=<i>$, $H_2=\{\pm1, \pm j\}=<j>$ and $H_3=\{\pm1, \pm k\}=<k>$ .Finally $H_o \subset H_s$, for all $s=1,2,3$

Comment: You're welcome ;-)